Potential difference between two non-grounded equipotential plate
I am attempting to solve for the potential difference between two non-grounded equipotential plates using Poisson's PDE. The relevant Maxwell equation considered is $∇⋅E=\rho$, where $E$ represents the electric displacement field and $\rho$ denotes the charge density. In the absence of free charge ($\rho = 0$), this equation simplifies to:
$$∇⋅E = 0.$$
The relevant boundary condition for the metal surface is:
$$∫∂Ω⋅=0.$$
For one electrode, I found that, it needs to be solved twice to get the actual constant potential at the electrode where in both cases the bottom plate is usually grounded and potentials set to 1 and 0 respectively on the electrode. Thus the Actual situation = potential *(Case A) + Case B.
But what should be the appropriate boundary conditions when two electrodes (neither grounded) are parallel with constant but unknown potentials.

Use mathjax for equation
